# Unable to connect IBM Flex compute node to network

Tags: networking, vlan, ibm

I am  having a problem wiht configuring IBM/LENOVO FLEX SYSTEM's networking.

The problem is that the node sees 9+ different interfaces where 2 are active but without a connection.

We bought the system from a old company pre configured, and are not able to factory reset the settings due to losing all the firmware updates. (at least that's what i'm told)

The configuration goes through a small LAN network, and the node is supposed to connect with to public network using a static ip address

IPs (dummy):

LAN:

- 192.168.80.80 (CMM)
- 192.168.80.81 (IO Module 1)
- 192.168.80.82 (IO Module 2)
- 255.255.0.0 (Subnet mask)

public:

- 123.123.123.133 (router/firewall)
- 123.123.123.134 (Supposed to be FLEX Node)
- 123.123.123.252 (Subnet mask)